# Can a Linux service be run as an application?

Tags: linux, testing, service

Can a Linux service be run as an application?

I am working on developing a program that will run as a Linux service. Is there any reason I cannot run it from the command line as a normal application for the purposes of development and testing?

Answer (score 0):

No reason at all. There are plenty of Linux services that do exactly as you've described, and take a switch to indicate whether they should start up in daemon mode.